# How can i check the hosting model in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I recently switched from OutOfProcess to the InProcess hosting model in my web.config file.
How can i inspect that i did it the correct way? How can i see what the hosting model is of sites within IIS?

Comment: Can this section answer your question? It mentioned to set `<PropertyGroup><AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel></PropertyGroup>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#out-of-process-hosting-model

Comment: I also found `The <processModel> element was not modified in IIS 10.0.`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel#compatibility

Comment: You should be able to run a report and tell https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics There wouldn't be any other easy ways, because such configuration is not exposed in IIS Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can get info about the hosting model, albiet indirectly. Anywhere you have access to an `HttpContext` object, for example in a controller, you can do this:

```
IServerVariablesFeature serverVars = HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();
if (serverVars == null) {
    //IIS Version not available probably because site is running out of process.

} else {
    //Site appears to be running under IIS
    string iisVersion = serverVars?["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
    string appPoolId = serverVars?["APP_POOL_ID"];
}
```

At that top of that file you need this using statement `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;`

You can learn more about IIS server vars here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN